# show data in textview from sqlite database in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i'm  trying to show data in textviews from database in android but it show run time erroe.. i am create database file as..

```
package com.example.databasetest;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "teacher";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "teacher_table";

    private static final String NAME = "teacher_name";
    private static final String FATHER_NAME = "father_name";
    private static final String MOTHER_NAME = "mother_name";

    SQLiteDatabase data=this.getWritableDatabase();

    Context ctx;



    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        ctx=context;
        Log.d("DATABASE OPERATION", "DATABASE CREATED");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        data=db;
          db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                    + BaseColumns._ID + " id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + NAME + " TEXT,"
                    + FATHER_NAME + " TEXT,"
                    + MOTHER_NAME + " TEXT,"
                    + ");");
        Log.d("DATABASE OPERATION", "TABLE CREATED");


    }
     public void open() throws SQLException
     {
         DBHelper db1 = new DBHelper(ctx);
            data = db1.getWritableDatabase();
     }

     public void close()
     {
         data.close();
     }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXCEPTION EXISTS");
        onCreate(db);       
    }
    public void onInsert(DBHelper db,String name,String f_name, String m_name)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sql= db.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put("teacher_name",name);
        cv.put("father_name", f_name);
        cv.put("mother_name", m_name);
        sql.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        Log.d("DATABASE OPERATION", "ONE ROW INSERTED.....");
    }

    public Cursor getInformation(DBHelper dop)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase SQ=dop.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] coloumns={NAME,FATHER_NAME,MOTHER_NAME};
        Cursor CR=SQ.query(TABLE_NAME, coloumns, null, null, null, null, null);
        return CR;

    }


}
```

and java file as...

```
package com.example.databasetest;



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ShowDetail extends Activity{
    TextView NAME,FATHERNAME,MOTHERNAME;
    String name,fathername,mothername;
    Context ctxx=this;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show_data);
        NAME=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        FATHERNAME=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.father_name);
        MOTHERNAME=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mother_name);
         List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        DBHelper DB= new DBHelper(ctxx);
        DB.open();
        Cursor CR=DB.getInformation(DB);
        if (CR.moveToFirst()) {
         do {

             list.add(CR.getString(0));

             name=CR.getString(0);

             fathername=CR.getString(1);

             mothername=CR.getString(2);



         } while (CR.moveToNext());
      }
      if (CR != null && !CR.isClosed()) {
         CR.close();
      }
      if(DB!=null)
      {
          DB.close();
      }

      NAME.setText(name);
      FATHERNAME.setText(fathername);
      MOTHERNAME.setText(mothername);


    }
}
```

and log cate show error as.....

```
05-07 06:25:59.173: D/gralloc_goldfish(918): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-07 06:26:15.483: E/SQLiteLog(918): (1) AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
05-07 06:26:15.483: D/AndroidRuntime(918): Shutting down VM
05-07 06:26:15.483: W/dalvikvm(918): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE teacher_table (_id id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, teacher_name TEXT,father_name TEXT,mother_name TEXT,);
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1672)
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1603)
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at com.example.databasetest.DBHelper.onCreate(DBHelper.java:38)
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at com.example.databasetest.DBHelper.<init>(DBHelper.java:23)
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at com.example.databasetest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:46)
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-07 06:26:15.553: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

please help me to fix the error

Comment: Remove id  before INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT and also remove comma after last TEXT.

Comment: we already told you about this mistake in the early question

Comment: still give error after correct this error

Answer (score 1):

Your create `table sql command` is wrong. corrected with below

```
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + NAME + " TEXT,"
                + FATHER_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + MOTHER_NAME + " TEXT"
                + ");");
```

Comment: Fixed the comma in the last field.

Comment: @DerGolem Ohhh Thanks. I did not see. `You have Owl Eye!!!!!`

Comment: Never mind. My pleasure. `Hawk Eye` is my name among the Lakotas... ;)

Comment: it still give same error after fix the comma....

Comment: @MonikaKrail Just Copy and Paste the command in my answer.

Comment: database is created but not show data in textview

Answer (score 0):

> CREATE TABLE teacher_table (_id id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
>   teacher_name TEXT,father_name TEXT,mother_name TEXT,);

There's a error in your query.

```
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                    + BaseColumns._ID + " id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + NAME + " TEXT,"
                    + FATHER_NAME + " TEXT,"
                    + MOTHER_NAME + " TEXT"
                    + ");");
```

Why _id & id for Primary key? also you added comma(,) here

```
MOTHER_NAME + " TEXT," <-- which is not needed.
```

Comment: still show error after fix the query

Comment: @MonikaKrail Since you changed the Schema, either you need to uninstall and install the app again or you need to increment Database Version to reflect the change but you need to implement onUpgrade method if you gonna try second method.